# Retrieving packaged(Managed ) objects custom fields into Eclipse with Force.com IDE to deploy to another org

Tags: force.com, salesforce-id, ant, eclipse, force.com-ide

I added the following code in package.xml

```
<types>
 <members>SCSCHAMPS__Job__c</members>
 <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

But, After I am trying to deploy this object is coming under 'Delete' (apply Action). How can I move all the custom fields which are in packaged object to another org (More than 50 fields in each packaged object)?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is part of a namespace it cannot be taken out of the containing package and deployed to another org. Instead you need to install that package on your target org.

Comment: Hey Phil,
Thanks for reply if I install same package into another org we get the fields but we cannot get the custom fields which are created later.Is their any alternative solution to get the custom fields which are created in packaged(Managed) object

Comment: You can pull any custom fields of your own (i.e. the non-packaged custom fields) down as meta data and deploy them as you need. It is specifically the fields that originate from a package with which you can't do what you're trying to do. If you are talking about additional fields added to the package later, you need to do an upgrade install of the package to get those new fields.